# Unable to Change Spinner dropdown icon

Tags: android, xml, android-spinner

I want to change spinner dropdown icon to a location icon  i went through a stack thread and i did modifications according to that. Here is what it is

```
 <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner22"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        style="@style/SpinnerTheme"
        android:gravity="end" />
```

In style.xml and style.xml(v21) i made

```
<style name="SpinnerTheme" parent="android:Widget.Spinner">
<item name="android:background">@drawable/bg_spinner</item>
```

I created a drawable resource file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item>

    <layer-list>

        <item>
            <shape>
                <gradient android:angle="90" android:endColor="#ffffff" 
android:startColor="#ffffff" android:type="linear" />

                <stroke android:width="0.33dp" android:color="#0fb1fa" />

                <corners android:radius="0dp" />

                <padding android:bottom="3dp" android:left="3dp" android:right="3dp" android:top="3dp" />
            </shape>
        </item>

        <item android:right="5dp">

            <bitmap android:gravity="center_vertical|right" android:src="@drawable/spinnericon" />

        </item>

    </layer-list>

</item>
```

This is my spinnericon.xml  drawable resource file

```
<vector android:height="24dp" android:tint="#FFFFFF"
android:viewportHeight="24.0" android:viewportWidth="24.0"
android:width="24dp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<path android:fillColor="#FF000000" android:pathData="M10,6L8.59,7.41 13.17,12l-4.58,4.59L10,18l6,-6z"/>
```

Java code

```
    Spinner spinner12 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner22);
    final TextView tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);

    String[] plants12 = new String[]{
            "LOCATIONS",
            "Mangalore",
            "Bangalore (coming soon)",

    };

    ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,plants12
    );



    spinnerArrayAdapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);


    spinner12.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter1);
```

This is the preview i am getting in android studio

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOmUC.png)

The error log cat (small part)

```
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Binary XML file line #61: Error inflating class Spinner
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #61: Error inflating class Spinner
 Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable com.example.EduMangalore:drawable/bg_spinner with resource ID #0x7f070067
 Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/bg_spinner.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f070067
```

Can anyone help me

Comment: mention #13,61  line of your layout

Comment: from my activity layout or java ?

Comment: I think may be issue with your `@drawable/spinnericon` icon try to use `png` or `jpeg` icon instead of `vector` drawable

Answer (score 0):

Try to apply following style to your spinner using

```
  style="@style/SpinnerTheme"

<style name="SpinnerTheme" parent="android:Widget.Spinner">
<item name="android:background">@drawable/bg_spinner</item>
</style>
```

Replace the arrow_down_gray with your arrow

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item>

    <layer-list>

        <item>
            <shape>
                <gradient android:angle="90" android:endColor="#ffffff" android:startColor="#ffffff" android:type="linear" />

                <stroke android:width="0.33dp" android:color="#0fb1fa" />

                <corners android:radius="0dp" />

                <padding android:bottom="3dp" android:left="3dp" android:right="3dp" android:top="3dp" />
            </shape>
        </item>

        <item android:right="5dp">

            <bitmap android:gravity="center_vertical|right" android:src="@drawable/arrow_down_gray" />

        </item>

    </layer-list>

</item>

 </selector>
```